# Drupal 7 Editing user profile page

Tags: drupal, hook, profile, editing

I've added custom fields to my user registration form, i.e date of birth which is set as a Date field and the widget is a select list. I have only ticked the year, month and day attributes in the field settings and on the registration form this works exactly as expected. However, on the Profile page which simply displays the user information, it displays the date of birth with the actual day, the date and the time?!! E.g Tuesday, 29th February 1980 - 00:00.

Does anyone know how I can remove the time from this? I've tried using a hook such as hook_profile_alter but it doesn't work. I don't think this page is an actual form is it so THEME_NAME_form_alter doesn't work either.

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375674/how-can-a-custom-drupal-date-format-be-added

Answer (score 0):

Go to `admin/config/people/accounts/display` and in your date of birth row, select the config icon (looks like a gear). From here, look for `

> To add or edit options, visit Date and time settings.

There you can configure data and time settings to the way you want them.